# git submodule conflicted pushed

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-merge, git-submodules

I have a really weird, bad scenario here.  Disclaimer, I'm new to git, and I've kind of screwed up.

SO I have lots of submodules in my fork, based on monodevelop.

**First**: I couldn't even update my submodules using 
`git submodule update --init --recursive`.
I tried bunch of similar commands, with rebase, foreach, etc.  So I finally got the latest using   `git submodule foreach git pull origin master`.  After this I got all my files.  I then committed and pushed my changes

**Now**: I just noticed that all my submodules have conflicts.  <<<<<<< HEAD, etc.  I have no idea where these came from, and I don't know how to fix these.

git status says everything is up-to-date.  submodule update says everything is up to date, even with force.  git fetch says everything is up-to-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who messes  up their submodules.  I also got some help from my friend on this.

What I had done was merge the submodules and commit them into my master.  General rule of thumb is I shouldn't do that, and instead make separate pull request to the submodule repo with the changes.

Anyways, I just went into each submodule directory, `git log # hit q to cancel out of the entire output.`.  When I got the commit sha for the right commit I want to go back to.
Then I did `git reset --hard c5652 # Partial commit id, if no other branch or file have that name.`  This is the fix for my issue.

I'm not crystal clear on the whole workings, and I'll definitely be reading more.

Comment: putting a submodule content into master is indeed not good: it removes the gitlink entry I mention in my answer and replaces it with a regular folder. The `reset --hard` is a good move. +1

Comment: @VonC Yes, that's where i screwed up. I wasn't aware that it would mess up the gitlink. It was out of ignorance, I should've paid better attention to what was getting committed.  I'm glad its resolved now. :)

Answer (score 1):

`git submodule update --init --recursive` would update your submodules to a specific SHA1, recorded in the index of your main repo (as a [**gitlink entry**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)).

If you need for a submodule to follow a branch, you can convert that submodule declaration in order to make it follow that branch with (after the init step) a `git submodule update --recursive --remote`.
See "[Git submodules: Specify a branch/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309)"